# Force methods to respect readonly signature in interface

Tags: typescript, readonly-variable

This resembles [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61166520/typescript-class-implements-interface-does-not-respect-readonly-modifier), but *not* a duplicate IMHO

```js
class Person {
  constructor(public age: number, public name: string){} 
}

interface AbstractVisitor {
  visit(_: Readonly<Person>): void;
}

class ConcreteVisitor implements AbstractVisitor {
  visit(p: Person) { p.name = "moish"; }
}
```

How come `ConcreteVisitor` does *not* respect<sup>1</sup> the `Readonly` property in the interface ?

---

<sup>1</sup> no errors with `npx tsc --target es2020 --strict main.ts`

Comment: *"but not a duplicate IMHO"* Can you tell us *why* you think the answers there don't apply to this question? Or perhaps the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57166390/why-typescript-allows-referencing-assigning-a-readonly-type-property-by-mutable), since all `Readonly<T>` does is mark all properties `readonly`? Or [any of these](/search?q=%5Btypescript%5D+readonly+allows+assignment)? Fundamentally, `readonly` is **really weak** and easily lost.

Comment: I do not change an attribute of the interface, but rather try to force that the obligations of the interface are fulfilled by implementing classes

Comment: Right, but again, fundamentally the problem is as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57168250/157247).

Comment: In the context of visitor, it's very common to get an obligation that the underlying visited element is not changed. the `Readonly` in the interface is supposed to guard on the input.

Comment: As [the answer I've pointed to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57168250/157247) says, the `readonly` modifier was an addition, and it's really weak, because making it properly strong would have broken backward compatibility. If you really want to enforce that, I don't think TS can help much, as covered there. You'll need a runtime proxy (literally [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) or wrapper with getters) or [frozen object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), unfortunately.

Comment: It pretty much is a duplicate; the issue is that assignability doesn't care about `readonly`, and that's what the other question asks.  If someone were to write an answer here it would be essentially a duplicate of the other answer.  Anyone looking for the answer to this question would get their answer by following the link above, so the standard approach here is to mark this as a duplicate (but don't delete it!) and people with your question will find their answer.